# xml record id with one increment

Tags: xml, excel

[image]

See the image above, each time I would like to increment my record with 1 so I get the xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <record1>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Sales>16753</Sales>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Quarter>Qtr 3</Quarter>
     </record1>
     <record2>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
        <Sales>14808</Sales>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Quarter>Qtr 4</Quarter>
     </record2>
 </data-set>
```

How is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that... (not a serious question, I know some people have some ideas)

Comment: This xml structure is used in an online survey tool. I want to make the survey in excel and then upload this to the survey website but I can only upload xml files that use this particular xml structure.

Comment: The online survey website has an online toolbox inwhich you can build your survey but that takes a lot of time (eg pushing a lot of buttons). Copy-pasting the questions in Excel and than export this to an xml file saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your spreadsheet that indicates the row number, give it a header of "RowNumber", then include it in the range you are exporting.

Exporting them as "", "" will cause problems for the programs that will use that XML in the future, because it will see them as different types of rows.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately adding an extra column with a "RowNumber" tag will not work for me. 

This xml structure is used in an online survey tool. I want to make the survey in excel and then upload this to the survey website but I can only upload xml files that use this particular xml structure.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you want that xml structure? I would recommend something like an `id` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <record>
        <id>1</id>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Sales>16753</Sales>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Quarter>Qtr 3</Quarter>
     </record>
     <record>
        <id>2</id>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
        <Sales>14808</Sales>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Quarter>Qtr 4</Quarter>
     </record>
 </data-set>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately adding an extra column with an id tag will not work for me. 

This xml structure is used in an online survey tool. I want to make the survey in excel and then upload this to the survey website but I can only upload xml files that use this particular xml structure.